# Python POS tagging: return the most common POS for a word, after training

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nlp, pos-tagger

I am trying to write a code that will create a dictionary with key(word), values(POS tags that word appears with + respective count). **The final goal is to know what POS tag is most frequent for a given word**

An example:
`most_common({"NOUN": 2, "DET": 5, "ADP": 1 }) returns "DET"` because the given word appears most frequently as a determiner.

First, I want to train my code on a small annotated corpus. This is what I have so far:

```
import pprint

trainfile = open("small_train.connlu")
list_of_lists = []
for line in trainfile:
    stripped_line = line.strip()
    line_list = stripped_line.split()
    list_of_lists.append(line_list)

list_keys = [] #a list that will contain all the keys (including duplicates)
list_values = [] #a list that will contain all the values

for line in list_of_lists:
    if line == []:
        pass
    elif line != []:
        list_keys.append(line[1]) # second column of the file contains all words
        list_values.append(line[3]) # fourth column of the file contains all POS tags (see below)

list_keys = [key.lower() for key in list_keys] #lowercase all keys - 'The' and 'the' should be assigned the same POS
```

I am stuck at this point. I now need to create a dictionary with all the words that appeared in the corpus followed by the respective POS tags they appeared with (and the count of how many times each word appeared with a certain POS tag). This is the closest I have got:

```
dict = {}

for key in range(len(list_keys)):
    dict[list_keys[key]] = list_values[key]

pprint.pprint(dict)
```

This returns keys with a correct POS tag, however, I don't know how to implement the count. Anything I have tried has resulted in errors.

This is how the training data is formatted (small_train.connlu)

```
1   The       _   DET   _ _ _ _ _ _
2   hottest   _   ADJ   _ _ _ _ _ _
3   item      _   NOUN  _ _ _ _ _ _
4   on        _   ADP   _ _ _ _ _ _
5   Christmas _   PROPN _ _ _ _ _ _
6   wish      _   NOUN  _ _ _ _ _ _
7   lists     _   NOUN  _ _ _ _ _ _
8   this      _   DET   _ _ _ _ _ _
9   year      _   NOUN  _ _ _ _ _ _
10  is        _   AUX   _ _ _ _ _ _
11  nuclear   _   ADJ   _ _ _ _ _ _
12  weapons   _   NOUN  _ _ _ _ _ _
13  .         _   PUNCT _ _ _ _ _ _

1   I         _   PRON  _ _ _ _ _ _
2   wish      _   VERB  _ _ _ _ _ _
3   you       _   PRON  _ _ _ _ _ _
4   all       _   DET   _ _ _ _ _ _
5   of        _   ADP   _ _ _ _ _ _
6   the       _   DET   _ _ _ _ _ _
7   best      _   ADJ   _ _ _ _ _ _
```

I would be very grateful if someone could help. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: what exactly is your expected output? Is it `{'the': 'DET', 'hottest': 'ADJ' ...}` and then you want to have some other ke with the count and other aggregates, or just the count and no exact words?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your list_of_lists is of the following format:

```
list_of_lists=[["","THE","","DET"],["","hottest","","ADJ"],["","the","","NOUN"],["","the","","DET"]]
```

You can create a dictionary of dictionaries where the key is the word and the value is another dictionary where the key is the pos tag and value is its frequency for the corresponding word.

```
# A dictionary of dictionaries
word_map = {}

# Iterate through the list of lists that has been prepared after parsing the file.
for line in list_of_lists:
        # Convert the word to lowercase
        word = line[1].lower()
        pos_tag = line[3]
        
        # If we have seen the word before.
        if word in word_map:
            
            # Get the inner dictionary for this word which contains the frequency of the pos tags for this word
            pos_tags_for_current_word = word_map[word]
             
            # If this pos tag has already been seen for this word then increment the frequency by 1
            if pos_tag in pos_tags_for_current_word:
                pos_tags_for_current_word[pos_tag] += 1
            # If the pos tag has been seen for the first time then add a new entry to the dictionary with a  frequency 1
            else:
                pos_tags_for_current_word[pos_tag] = 1
        
        # If the word has been seen for the first time then add a new entry for the word with value as a dictionary and the current pos tag with frequency 1.
        else:
            word_map[word] = {pos_tag:1}
```

Printing word_map gives us

```
{'hottest': {'ADJ': 1}, 'the': {'DET': 2, 'NOUN': 1}}
```

Now iterate through this dictionary and find the pos tag with highest frequency for every word.

```
for word in word_map:
        print(word, max(word_map[word].items(), key = lambda entry : entry[1]))
```

Here is the output of the for loop mentioned above:

```
the ('DET', 2)
hottest ('ADJ', 1)
```

This is just a shorthand way of finding out the entry with maximum value in any dictionary.

```
max(word_map[word].items(), key = lambda entry : entry[1])
```

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full, more functional way of parsing the file into a format you can do other operations on (list of dict) and finding the most common type of word:

```py
def parse_connlu(lines: list) -> list:
    # return a list of dict of the connlu file
    items = [[item for item in line.split()
              if item != '']
             for line in lines
             if line != '']
    return [{'pos': int(item[0]),
             'word': item[1].lower(),
             'type': item[3]}
            for item in items]

def read_connlu(path: str) -> list:
    # read the connlu file (will return list[dict])
    with open(path, 'r') as file:
        lines = file.read().splitlines()
        return parse_connlu(lines)

def count(items: list) -> dict:
    # count unique elements in list
    unique = set(items)
    return {i: items.count(i) for i in unique}

def most_common(items: list):
    # get the most commen item
    counts = count(items)
    # {'NOUN': 5, 'PROPN': 1, 'VERB': 1, 'ADP': 2, 'DET': 4, 'PRON': 2, 'AUX': 1, 'PUNCT': 1, 'ADJ': 3}
    return max(counts, key=counts.get)

words = read_connlu('./small_train.connlu')
# gives us:
# [{'pos': 1, 'type': 'DET', 'word': 'the'},
#  {'pos': 2, 'type': 'ADJ', 'word': 'hottest'},
# ...

answer = most_common([i['type'] for i in words])
print(answer)
# gives us: NOUN
```

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful!! :)